# jquery selector: anchor elements by name

Tags: jquery, html, selector, anchor

I'm new to jQuery so this is probably simple, but...

If I have this HTML:

```
<a name="foo">Foo</a>
```

how can I select the anchor element by its name `foo`? It doesn't have an `id` property.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('a[name=foo]')
```

It's called a [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).